# Procedure com EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle

Criei um script em Oracle que roda em um owner, faz o select em vários outros e faz insert ou update em outro owner em outro servidor através um linkedserver.

Devido ao fato de fazer select em vários owners criei os selects desse modo:

```
  vSQL_STMT := 'SELECT campo1, campo2... FROM empresa.TBLTABELA A WHERE CDNIVELCTL = 0 AND STCOTEJ = 'S' ...'

  vSQL_STMT2 := REPLACE( vSQL_STMT, 'empresa', 'XXXX' || rec.CDBASEDADOS );
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL_STMT2 into vNRITENSCOT,vNRITENSSOBRASCTB,vNRITENSSOBRASFIS,vNRCOTDIRETO,...
```

A variavel `empresa` é alterada em tempo de execução para fazer o select no owner correto.

E executo `INSERT` através do LINKEDSERVER.

```
  INSERT INTO TABELA@LINKEDSERVER VALUES( vCDJOB, vNRITENSCOT,....
```

Se executo o script manualmente no SQLDeveloper tudo corre normalmente e funciona como esperado.

Porém, se transformo esse script em procedure para roda-lo automaticamente atraves de um programa, apesar de não ocorrer erro o script não funciona, ou seja, a tabela do servidor não é alimentada.

Alguém sabe como resolver essa questão?

Comment: Já tive problemas parecidos quando o Owner aonde a package foi criada não tinha grants para os outros owners, não gerava exceção, apenas quando o execute immediate estava acompanhado de um bloco de exception.